# Automapper "IsNull" Destination postfix not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have the following code  :

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var srcClass = new SourceClass { Value1 = null, Value2 = 10, Value3 = 20 };
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPostfixes("IsNull");
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>();
        });
        var targetClass = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, TargetClass>(srcClass);

    }
}
public class SourceClass
{
    public int? Value1 { get; set; }
    public int? Value2 { get; set; }
    public int? Value3 { get; set; }
}
public class TargetClass
{
    public bool Value1IsNull{ get; set; }
    public bool Value2IsNull { get; set; }
    public bool Value3IsNull { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting the targetClass instance to have the following values : true, false,false;
but I'm receiving the opposite : false,true,true.

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: What you need here is to tell AM what you want by creating a map from int? to bool.

Answer (score 3):

It is because when we convert integer to Boolean it returns false for null and true for values.

```
            int? a;
            a = null;
            //Convert null to boolean
            bool a1 = Convert.ToBoolean(a);
            Console.WriteLine("Null Value - " + a1);
            a = 1;
            //Convert integer value to boolean
            a1 = Convert.ToBoolean(a);
            Console.WriteLine("Have Value - " + a1);
            var srcClass = new SourceClass { Value1 = null, Value2 = 1, Value3 = 20 };
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RecognizeDestinationPostfixes("IsNull");
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>();
            });
            var targetClass = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, TargetClass>(srcClass);
            Console.WriteLine(targetClass.Value1IsNull+" - " +targetClass.Value2IsNull+" - " +targetClass.Value3IsNull);
```

Output:

```
Null Value - False
Have Value - True
False - True - True
```